# Increment time value for 2 fields for every Thread and loop in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jsr223, jmeter-4.0, blazemeter

I have to Schedule a Meeting, In the particular post request body data I have to give from and to time. Every time the From & To time hours be different and time should not overlap.

For this requirement I tried the below code using `JSR223 Sampler`, But the issue I'm facing here is that only one time gets incremented and for every thread and loop .The value is same and it is not incrementing. Every Thread the time value should be incremented. Please let me know how I achieve it , as below code is returning same value for each Thread

```
def now = new Date()
log.info('Before: ' + now.format('HH:mm'))
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def nowPlus60Mins = now + 60.minutes
    def nowPlus15Mins = nowPlus60Mins + 15.minutes
    log.info('After: ' + nowPlus60Mins.format('HH:mm'))
    log.info('End: ' + nowPlus15Mins.format('HH:mm'))
vars.put("AfterTime",nowPlus60Mins.format('HH:mm'));
vars.put("EndTime",nowPlus15Mins.format('HH:mm'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run more than 1 iteration in 1 minute - it's absolutely expected that you will get the same generated offsets because given your [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) setting the value will update every minute.

Also you don't need any scripting, you can achieve the same using [__timeShift() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) directly in your request body:

- plus 60 minutes: `${__timeShift(HH:mm,,PT60M,,)}`
- plus 15 minutes: `${__timeShift(HH:mm,,PT15M,,)}`

[image]

More information: [Creating Dates in JMeter Using the TimeShift Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to affect all thread you must use JMeter properties, represented in script as `props`:

```
props.put("AfterTime",nowPlus60Mins.format('HH:mm'));
props.put("EndTime",nowPlus15Mins.format('HH:mm'));
```

To get the property value outside JSR223 Sampler using __P function as `${__P(AfterTime,)}`

In JSR223 get property with `props.get("EndTime")`